# AngularJS: input[number] with placeholder & ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, placeholder, ionic-framework, angular-ngmodel

I have the following input field in my view

```
<input type="number" min="0" placeholder="7500" ng-model="totalClicks" required>
```

What I want now is to set the model variable total `totalClicks` to an initial value that is not reflected to the UI unless the user makes an input.

If I initialize with

```
$scope.totalClicks = {};
```

or

```
$scope.totalClicks = '';
```

then the placeholder is shown correctly until the user makes an input. However, the model variable totalClicks is not updated and remains as initialized.

If I set it to

```
$scope.totalClicks = 0;
```

then `0` is shown in the input and the placeholder isn't but the model is updated.

Any advices?

**UPDATE:**

Added

```
$scope.funnel = {};
$scope.funnel.totalClicks = 9;
<input type="number" min="0" placeholder="7500" ng-model="funnel.totalClicks" required>
```

Now the placeholder is shown on page load but `$scope.funnel.totalClicks` remains `9` when I change the input

**UPDATE #2:**
Here's an example on plunker. There're 2 text boxes bound to the same model therefore when I change the model in one input box the other one should change as well. (Example includes ionic framework)
http://plnkr.co/edit/F4fOGMBA8eFJ9vdyuDvm

Comment: Let me cite: *"Whenever you have ng-model there's gotta be a dot in there somewhere"* ... see for example http://stackoverflow.com/a/23043335/1679310

Comment: The current codes behaves as required I guess, isn't it ? 
Check the jsfiddle here I created 

http://jsfiddle.net/a5UyU/

Comment: See solution below, it doesn't work (also not with a dot)

Comment: I'm using angularJS as a part of the ionicframework. Can this be related to the problem?

Comment: Have you checked the jsfiddle, can you elaborate which feature you wanted is not available, am I missing something ?

Comment: Yeah I did and Im wondering why it works there :/

Comment: @nephix some files are missing [one](http://code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/angular/angular-route.js) and [two](http://code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/angular/angular-touch.js).

Comment: Oh thx! I fixed missing files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following  is the working example for updating the totalClicks ngModel.

```
<html ng-app="ExamplesApp">  
  <head> 
    <script src="angular.js"></script>   
  </head>  
 <body ng-controller="ExCtrl">
   <input type="number" min="0" placeholder="7500" ng-model="totalClicks" required>
   <button ng-click="clicks()">Click</button>   
   <script type="text/javascript">
     angular.module('ExamplesApp',[]);
     angular.module('ExamplesApp')
      .controller('ExCtrl',function($scope){
        $scope.totalClicks = '';         
        $scope.clicks= function(){
          alert($scope.totalClicks);
        };
      });
   </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

JSFiddle :  **http://jsfiddle.net/StT2y/2/**

Comment: ok I totally missed this, what is it thats done differently here :-/

Comment: I updated the plunker.I don't know about this "iconic.js".Actually, this is not available in the concerned uri.So, angular doesn't able create a module for the app.If i removed "iconic" dependency in module defining statement, everything is working fine!! http://plnkr.co/edit/5foq7qP4scUdUAkrWMKQ

Comment: Hm so the problem is likely to be caused by the ionic framework I guess

Comment: yes, exactly! iconic files are not loaded into the app.Just check Dev tools, after running the app.

Answer (score 0):

define the value and model as a property on the totalClicks object.

```
$scope.totalClicks = {}
$scope.totalClicks.amount = 0;

<input type="number" min="0" placeholder="7500" ng-model="totalClicks.amount" required>
```

Comment: We might need to add  $scope.totalClicks={} before assigning  $scope.totalClicks.amount = 0 . Isn't it ?? or was it obvious :|

Comment: see the above edit. you need to defined $scope.totalClicks before you can set a property on it

Comment: Your solution doesn't show the placeholder it displays `0` in the input field. Am I missing something?

Comment: Oh! I misread the question. Just remove the second line then (don't declare ```totalClicks.amount = 0```)

Comment: $scope.totalClicks is then Object {} during runtime

Comment: as I already corrected in the previous example, don't declare ```$scope.funnel = {};```

Comment: If I dont do it: TypeError: Cannot set property 'totalClicks' of undefined